# Blank prototype cells in Storyboards

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableviewcontroller connected to a table view. I want to have a custom cell type in the table view. The custom cell should have three `UILabels` and a `UIImageView`.

I have designed the custom cell in the tableview (using a prototype cell) in the storyboard. I have created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and have linked the prototype cell to this class. I have also set the reuse identifier of the cell to be "ItemCell".

In the `UITableView` I have an add button. When I press this button new cells (custom cells) should be added to the tableview. They are (I can tell by the fact that I can select them) except they are blank (although the label should display something). The label is connected to the `UITableViewCell` subclass as a `IBOutlet` property and has a grey background so I can see its frame but all I see is a white row.

What's wrong?

This is the `viewDidLoad` method from the `UITableViewController`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[ItemCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Home";
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                                                                           target:self
                                                                                           action:@selector(addNewItem:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

This is the code from the `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ItemCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ItemCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.nameLabel.text = @"hello";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If you create you cell on a storyboard you don't need to register it's class yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using prototype cells then you specify the reuse identifier in the storyboard and cells are unpacked from there. By calling this code:

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[ItemCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"ItemCell"];
```

you are removing that registration and replacing it with a simple empty instance of the `ItemCell` class, so there will be no subviews and no populated outlets.

Remove that line of code to fix.

Comment: It worked. Can't believe it was that simple. Thank you!

Comment: Noticed something strange. Previously (when I was using the normal cells) I could press on one of them to present another view controller with the details of the cells using a navigation controller. Now, when I press on the custom cell it slides two identical view controllers from the right. Why two? It was working fine previously.

Comment: I guess you might have a segue connected to the prototype and also implement the delegate method to push something?

Comment: I only have the segue. No push method. As I said, before I switched to custom cells it was working fine.

Comment: My bad. I did have both segue and push. Fixed it. It's working fine now. I don't understand why it didn't act like this before though.